# Javascript Diferencia entre "colección" (collection) y "arreglo"(array)

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una "*colección*" (como la devuelta por querySelectorAll y un "*arreglo*" (array)?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar mas contexto de tu pregunta por favor?, has buscado o consultado algo?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Lo que devuelve `querySelectorAll()` es una colección de nodos HTML existentes en el DOM o en un elemento previamente definido, mientras que un arreglo, podríamos decir que es una lista, formada por valores o claves y valores.

Comment: Si son claves y valores entonces estariamos hablando de un objeto no @Triby ?

Comment: Considero que la pregunta es muy amplia y la teoría mínima para explicarla demasiado amplia luego entonces sugiero empieces por [leer sobre arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) y posterior [leer sobre NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) para que finalmente cuando existan dudas mas claras la pregunta entonces esté mejor enfocada

Comment: @BetaM, en sí, la definición de [_Array_ es un objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array). ¿El índice puede contar como clave?

Comment: cierto @Triby solo consideré que sería conveniente el OP conociera *visualmente* como se representarían ambos aunque concuerdo conrtigo

Comment: Buena observación, @BetaM, lamentablemente la pregunta es muy amplia y creo que no hay punto de comparación, tal vez si fuera _objetos_ vs _arreglos_ se puede ser más específico. De cualquier forma, no amerita una respuesta, pero sí puntos desde donde OP puede comenzar a investigar.

Answer (score 2):

Primero, hay una diferencia que es a nivel conceptual.

### Colección

Es un cierto número de *objetos*, que idealmente serán de un mismo *tipo* o *categoría*. (OJO, que uso aquí términos como *objeto*, *tipo* y *categoría* de forma bastante amplia y no me refiero a la programación o algún lenguaje de programación particular, sino más bien al concepto común de colección). Ejemplos de la vida real de colecciones puede ser una colección de gorras, de entradas a conciertos o la colección de ollas que solemos tener en la cocina. Una colección como tal no implica que los objetos que la componen tengan que tener un orden particular, ni la forma en la que estos se almacenan o se accede a ellos.

Al trasladar este concepto a la informática, suele mantenerse la parte esencial: Una colección es un grupo de valores u objetos que no tiene necesariamente un orden particular (aunque suele tenerlo), ni impone la forma en que cada uno de sus elementos puede accederse, que suele variar de una *colección* a otra.

### Arreglo

Un **arreglo** es una clase (o los objetos creados con ella) (ahora si, en algún lenguaje de programación) que tiene ciertas características y finalmente contiene referencias a un número variable de otros objetos o valores, conocidos como elementos. De esto que un arreglo **ES** una colección de objetos o valores que tiene una serie de características bien definidas, siendo la principal que sus elementos están ordenados y son accesibles a través de un índice numérico. De tal manera que puedo acceder a sus elementos utilizando su índice entre corchetes `[]`. Un arreglo de N elementos llamado `miArreglo`, contendrá los elementos `miArreglo[0], miArreglo[1], ... miArreglo[N-1]` hasta `miArreglo[N]`.

Encontramos lenguajes de programación que soportan arreglos con una cantidad fija de elementos y/o arreglos dinámicos (con una cantidad variable de elementos). Javascript soporta arreglos dinámicos.

Vamos a ver otra categoría:

### Listas

Las listas son objetos que también son colecciones de objetos, con algunas características similares y otras distintas a las de los arreglos.

## Respondiendo tu pregunta

Ahora si, la documentación suele utilizar de manera más o menos libre el término *colección*, y como ya hemos visto, hay diferentes clases que representan colecciones de objetos. En otras palabras:

**`Array` es un tipo particular de colección** y no tiene mucho sentido preguntar cuales son las diferencias entre un arreglo y una colección. Básicamente un arreglo **ES** una colección (con todas sus letras).

**Pero...**

Dado que pones el ejemplo del método [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es-ES/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), tu pregunta en realidad sería qué diferencia hay entre una [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es-ES/docs/Web/API/NodeList) —que es lo que devuelve dicho método— y un [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es-ES/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Estas clases, al ser ambas colecciones, tienen algunas similitudes, como que puede determinarse cuantos elementos tienen y puede iterarse por ellos. La diferencia principal radica en los otros métodos disponibles, de las que no haré una lista aquí, pues es bastante amplia, pero ya tienes referencias a la documentación, que te lo dejará en claro.

Por ejemplo, el arreglo tiene los métodos `push()`, `pop()`, `reverse()`, `shift()`, `slice()` y muchos otros, que no están disponibles en la lista, que tiene solo unos pocos. En cambio la lista tiene el método `item()` que no existe en el arreglo.

Generalmente, puedes *pasar* los elementos de una `NodeList` a un `Array` valiéndote del método `Array.from()`.

En el caso de la lista devuelta por `querySelectorAll()`, esta es estática y no hay mucho más que decir, pues va a contener los elementos que cumplieron con el criterio de búsqueda al invocar el método `querySelectorAll()`, si algo cambia después, no se ve reflejado en la lista.

En cambio, hay *`nodeList` vivas*, como la devuelta por `.childNodes`. Esta lista está directamente conectada al *DOM*, de manera que va a reflejar los elementos que existen en el momento de ejecutar cualquier código sobre ellas. Si creas un arreglo con los elementos de una lista viva, el arreglo va a contener una versión estática de los mismos, es decir, una fotografía de los elementos que tenía al momento de crear el arreglo, y no se va a actualizar conforme cambie el DOM.

Finalmente, te dejo algo de código para que veas como convertir de una lista a un arreglo y cómo iterar por ambos es posible.

```js
function ejecutarClick() {
  let matchList = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  //crear un arreglo basado en la lista
  let matchArray = Array.from(matchList);
  //veamos de que clase es cada uno
  console.log('Clases: ');
  console.log('Lista: ' + matchList.constructor.name);
  console.log('Arreglo: ' + matchArray.constructor.name); 
  console.log('Elementos de la lista:');
  matchList.forEach(
    function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
      console.log(currentIndex + ': ' + currentValue.innerHTML);
    }
  );
  console.log('Elementos del arreglo:');
  matchArray.forEach(
    function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
      console.log(currentIndex + ': ' + currentValue.innerHTML);
    }
  );
  matchArray.reverse();
  console.log('Elementos del arreglo en orden inverso, esto no puede hacerse con la lista');
  matchArray.forEach(
    function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
      console.log(currentIndex + ': ' + currentValue.innerHTML);
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hola</p>
  <p>Esto es una prueba</p>
  <button id="ejecutar" onclick="ejecutarClick()">Ejecutar</button>
</div>
```